# Why are some shortcuts not working on VS CODE?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Some shortcuts on vs code recently stopped working, like Ctrl + B was used to hide left pane, but now I can't use it, also earlier Alt + Shift + Down key was used to copy the line down, now, instead it is multiplying the arrow downwards. I have also checked key bindings and restarted it again, but still the problem exists. What to do?
Settings.json:

```json
{
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ],
    "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "liveshare.presence": false,
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "[json]": {

    
        "editor.quickSuggestions": {
            "strings": true
        },
        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace"
    },
    "json.schemas": [
        
    
    ],
    "[jsonc]": {

        "editor.quickSuggestions": {
            "strings": true
        },
        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace"
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the settings.json file. Had you installed another key mapping extension?

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik Updated settings.json in question & I haven't used any another keymapping extension.

Answer (score 3):

For troubleshooting the problem, you can open the command palette "`ctrl + shift + p`", then choose the command:

```
Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting
```

Afterwards, press one of the problematic keyboard shortcuts and see what will be returned on the output pane. For example, hitting `ctrl+b` should return something like this:

```
[renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, matched workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility, when: no when condition, source: built-in.
[renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: KeyB, keyCode: 66, key: b
[renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: KeyB, keyCode: 32 ('B')
[renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+B
```

From there, you can get a sense of what exactly is hapenning when you press your keyboard shortcut